# formatting of chat gpt responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formatting, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using chat gpt api on my react application. The problem i am facing is how to format the response coming from chat gpt. If is ask it to give me a response in table format it provides weird response I used pre tag to display text and response appear in this way image attached , but I want proper table just like chat gpt, in the same way if i ask for any list of items it display as a form of paragraph not on different line so how to do proper formatting of chat gpt response.

i want proper table and list as chat gpt shows but this is how i am receiving data
[this is how data is appearing when using pre tag but i want proper table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dImcc.jpg)

Comment: If that format is not good enough for you write a parser that can parse that format and output it however you want instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can tell ChatGPT how you want it to format its response. Try one of these prompts:

- what are the top 10 countries in the world in terms of population? format the answer as an HTML table
- what are the top 10 countries in the world in terms of population? format the answer as a JSON object with the keys rank, country, and population

Answer (score 4):

ChatGPT and OpenAI APIs can return the data in a format that works for you.
Just add the format instruction in your prompt.

Examples:

`Return the answer as a JSON object.`

`Do you know the 10 most popular books from Stephen King? Return an array of books in a JSON object.`

ChatGPT answer:

```json
{
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "The Shining",
      "year": 1977,
      "description": "A horror novel about a family that moves into an isolated hotel with a dark past."
    },
    {
      "title": "It",
      "year": 1986,
      "description": "A story about a group of friends who confront a shape-shifting evil entity in their small town."
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You can then fine-tune the result, with instructions like `ordered by {something}`, `group by {something}`

Answer (score 3):

The response from OpenAI API is in Markdown syntax. We can use some libraries to convert markdown to html (e.g., [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)).

For React environment, we can also use [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown), together with the plugin [remark-gfm](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-gfm) to render Markdown format with tables (see https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#use-a-plugin for reference).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other good answers here, I just wanted to share some thoughts that might help you or others reading this to better control the format of the AI's outputs.

I have seen varying results with the AI sometimes not returning the specified format.

Generally with OpenAi's endpoints I have found myself making small tweaks to the prompts/request, running it, and repeating that process until I get closer to my desired output and format.

Things you can try, that seem to improve the chances of it returning the desired format *more consistently*:

**1. In addition to saying "format as an HTML table" or "return as a JSON array", give it an example of the desired output.**

For example:

```
return as a JSON object in this format:
{
  "country" : "Brazil",
  "population: 213,429,381
}
```

Or

```
return the results as an HTML table. Use the following code snippet as an example of the format:
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Population</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Brazil</td>
  <td>213,429,381</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**2. Try using a different model.**

There are definitely differences I have seen between the `gpt-3.5-turbo` and `gpt-4` models.

**3. Try setting the ['temperature' property](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-temperature) to a lower value.**

This should reduce variance of the output (for better or for worse depending on what you are needing).

**4. Explore using [Functions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-functions).**

With the chat endpoint, they now have the ability to send up a function for the model to call. You can specify arguments for the functions, where you can say

```
functions : [{
    name: "make a table",
    description: "creates a table in valid HTML table format, that includes table headers",
    parameters: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        nameThisWhateverYouWantRawHTML: {
          type: "string",
          description: "the tabular data in HTML format: <table>...</table>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then in your prompt or chat messages include some instruction to trigger that function call.

**5. Set the [`n` property](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-n) in the request greater than 1.**

This will generate multiple options to choose from in the response. If the first option is in an invalid format, use the next one.

**6. Implement a retry strategy in your code.**

If a request ever returns an invalid format, run it again.